# Bundle install - GEMFILE NOT FOUND

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am having issues with running "bundle install" on macos. I get the following message after bundle install

```
bundle install
Ignoring ffi-1.9.23 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.9.23
Ignoring gem-wrappers-1.4.0 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine gem-wrappers --version 1.4.0
Ignoring gem-wrappers-1.3.2 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine gem-wrappers --version 1.3.2
Ignoring openssl-2.1.1 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine openssl --version 2.1.1
Could not locate Gemfile
```

Could you please help me?

Comment: are you sure you are doing `bundle install` from root of the project ?

Comment: you are not doing bundle from the app directory, navigate to correct directly where you can locate Gemfile

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you are not on the root folder of the project.

go in your terminal to the root folder of the project and then run bundle install there.

Answer (score 0):

Bundler uses the gem system, and the problems being displayed to you on the screen relate to that gem system. Try running the `gem pristine` commands it tells you to.

Comment: It's possible that your Ruby directory in rvm is corrupted -- you could try rvm installing a more recent version of Ruby or rvm removing 2.4.1 and rvm reinstalling it. Also, did you brew install openssl, or are you using the system openssl? There are known problems with that as well.

Comment: Also, when you post command output, it's important to also post the command that generated it.

Comment: Ignoring ffi-1.9.25 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.9.25
Ignoring ffi-1.9.23 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.9.23
Ignoring gem-wrappers-1.4.0 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine gem-wrappers --version 1.4.0
Ignoring gem-wrappers-1.3.2 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine gem-wrappers --version 1.3.2
Ignoring nio4r-2.3.1 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine nio4r --version 2.3.1

Comment: Ignoring nio4r-2.3.1 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine nio4r --version 2.3.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.8.2 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.8.2
Ignoring openssl-2.1.1 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine openssl --version 2.1.1
Ignoring websocket-driver-0.7.0 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine websocket-driver --version 0.7.0
Error loading RubyGems plugin "/Users/ramsan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/gem-wrappers-1.4.0/lib/rubygems_plugin.rb": cannot load such file -- gem-wrappers (LoadError)

Comment: ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass

Comment: This is what I get when I run gem pristine

Comment: Which error? The Gemfile not found error, or the gem pristine errors?